# Efficiently reduce number of points in gps track by distance between points

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe containing gps coordinates (Timestamp, Latitude, Longitude) of vehicle tracks. The frequency is between 30 seconds between points and 1 second between points. This depends on some logic in gps receiver including speed but is not very reliable.

These tracks can be very long and contain many thousands of gps points. especially when a vehicle is moving slow or is at rest. The data looks like this:

| Timestamp | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 days 00:00:00 | 51.1513 | 9.61053 |
| 0 days 00:00:28 | 51.1513 | 9.61049 |
| 0 days 00:00:29 | 51.1513 | 9.61048 |
| 0 days 00:00:31 | 51.1513 | 9.61048 |
| 0 days 00:00:33 | 51.1513 | 9.61048 |

I want to reduce the size of the data frames by only including gps points which are at least 50 meters apart of the gps position before. The distance between two gps positions is calculated using the harvesine formula:

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt
def haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees) in meters
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    # Radius of earth in kilometers is 6371
    m = 6371000* c
    return m
```

Currently i use a very naive approach by looping over the dataframe and creating a mask containing elements at least 50 meters apart. But this is very inefficient and i am looking for an efficient way to calculated this for large data frames.

```
def reduce_gps(df): 
    mask = np.full(len(df), False)
    cpos = 0
    #print(cpos)
    lat_col = df_gps.columns.get_loc('Latitude')
    lon_col = df_gps.columns.get_loc('Longitude')
    for pos in range(len(mask)):
        if haversine(df.iloc[cpos, lat_col], df.iloc[cpos, lon_col], 
                     df.iloc[pos, lat_col], df.iloc[pos, lon_col]) > 50 or (pos==len(mask)-1):
            #print(pos)
            cpos = pos
            mask[pos] = True
    return df[mask]
```

The haversine formula can be vectorized if this is helpful:

```
def haversine_vec(df):   
    data = np.deg2rad(df[['Latitude', 'Longitude']])                     
    diff = data.shift() - data
    d = np.sin(diff['Latitude']/2)**2 + np.cos(data['Latitude'])*np.cos(data['Latitude'].shift()) * np.sin(diff['Longitude']/2)**2
    return 2 * 6371000 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(d))
```

I uploaded a small set of sample data here:

```
pd.read_csv('https://pastebin.com/raw/qeUDKr9z')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a list comprehension:

```
df['distance']=[haversine(df.Latitude[i],df.Longitude[i],df.Latitude[i+1],df.Longitude[i+1]) if i!=len(df)-1 else 0 for i in range(len(df))]

df[df.distance>50]
```